# Oracle query to parse column

Tags: c#, ajax, parsing, datatables, oracle12c

I have a debug log table in an Oracle 12c DB that I am trying to parse and display in a jQuery data table.

I am using the following query that works fine when I run it in SQL Developer windows but never ends executing in the web application.

The data looks something like below, stored in column DTEXT, and there are only 8500 rows.

```
SID[1769]:  USPPICKEVENTS[90] LVSPICKSQL[INSERT INTO DBMIRROR (...).
SID[130]:  USPPICKITEMS[131]. LVCMIRRORCOLLECTION.Count[0].
```

The number after SID is , well, SID; then the stored procedure name, the second number is line number inside SP and rest kind of description, and these are what I am trying to parse (i.e. SID, USP name, line number, description).

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT DTEXT, CHANGE_DATE, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), '\[([^]]+)\]', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS SID, 
SUBSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), INSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), ':', 1, 1) + 1, 
INSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), '[', 1, 2) - INSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), ':', 1, 1) - 1) AS USP, 
SUBSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), INSTR(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), ']', 1, 2) + 1) AS DESCR, 
regexp_substr(REPLACE(DTEXT, ' ', ''), '\[([^]]+)\]', 1, 2, NULL, 1) USP_LINENUM
FROM DEBUG_LOG) ;
```

1. Not sure if this is correct or efficient way of doing this, I am by no means an Oracle developer.
2. Not sure why when data is returned it keeps going and going and jQuery data table never populates.

This is the function to populate data table, web service URL is passed to it and the service uses above query and converts to JSON string.

```
function populateTable(ws_url, parameters, table) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ws_url,
        cache: false,
        data: parameters,
    }).done(function (result) {
        table.clear().draw();
        jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);

        if (jResult.length != 0) {
            table.rows.add(jResult).draw();
            table.columns([5]).visible(false);
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
        $('#divGrid').hide();
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a little bit simpler query?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'SID[1769]:  USPPICKEVENTS[90] LVSPICKSQL[INSERT INTO DBMIRROR (...).' from dual union all
  3     select 'SID[130]:  USPPICKITEMS[131]. LVCMIRRORCOLLECTION.Count[0].' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1) sid,
  7    regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) usp,
  8    regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) line,
  9    trim(substr(col, instr(col, ']', 1, 2) + 1)) description
 10  from test;

SID   USP             LINE  DESCRIPTION
----- --------------- ----- ----------------------------------------
1769  USPPICKEVENTS   90    LVSPICKSQL[INSERT INTO DBMIRROR (...).
130   USPPICKITEMS    131   . LVCMIRRORCOLLECTION.Count[0].

SQL>
```

- lines 1 - 4 represent sample data
- SID: give me the first number
- USP: give me the third *word*
- LINE: give me the 2nd number
- DESCRIPTION: string that follows the second closing square bracket

As of the rest (ajax, c# and stuff) - I can't help with that, sorry.